# "browse time machine backups" shows no backups when using a NAS, unless I manually start a backup first

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, nas, macos

I back up using Time Machine to a Synology NAS, using its built-in support for this. In general, it works great.

However — almost obviously — when I'm not *connected* to the NAS, I don't see any backups in "browse time machine backups".

The problem is that the state of "connected to the NAS" can apparently only be achieved by forcing a "backup now".  After a fairly short amount of time, Time Machine disconnects from the NAS and I am once again left backupless.

Worse, "connected to the NAS" is not something as simple as clicking on the NAS itself.  The time machine share and its attendant disk image is mounted automatically in the background as a result of Time Machine's internal functionality, and it's mounted `nobrowse`.  It seems slightly risky to connect to the backup share, and *very* risky to mount the disk image through some manual command-line shenanigans, given that there's a risk that two processes that don't recognize this is the same underlying storage might start simultaneously scribbling on it and corrupting my backups.

How can I tell Time Machine "connect to my backup drive, then just chill out, don't do a backup or anything"?